# Is it possible to add dropzone form by onclick javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropzone.js

Hello I am working with `[dropzone.js]` (drag-drop files library)
I want the user could click some button and the Dropzone form will be added. (I have already 1 dropzone form and after user click add,  the second Dropzone form will be shown.)

but my problem is after clicking add button, dropzone form is added successfully but cannot upload the file.  How should I do to make it upload like the first Dropzone form?    **(Oh and if I write the second dropzone form normally, it work fine. but if onclick add second dropzone-form  it's not work.)**

here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.0.1/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.js"></script>

<script>
count=2;
function add_ptg_input()   //onclick to add dropzone-form function
{ if(count<50)
    {
    var newspan = document.createElement('span');
    newspan.innerHTML = '<form id="uploadfree" class="dropzone dz-clickable" action="test2.php" method="post" style="width:400px;" > \
  <div class="dropzone-previews"></div> \
     <input type="text" name="free" /> \
    <button type="submit">Submit data and files!</button> \
    <div class="dz-default dz-message"><span>Drop files here to upload</span></div> \
    </form> ';
    document.getElementById('add_ptg').appendChild(newspan);

    count++;
    }   
}
</script>

<script>
  //Just a config to make dropzone can use with other form input 


    Dropzone.options.uploadfree = {

  autoProcessQueue: false,
  parallelUploads: 100,
  maxFiles: 100,

  init: function() {
    var myDropzone = this;

    this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      myDropzone.processQueue();
    });

    this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
    });
    this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
    });
    this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
    });
  }
}


</script>
</head>
```

...

```
     <body>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="add_ptg_input();" style="position:absolute; margin-left:10px;">Add</a>
            <div id="add_ptg">
            <form id="uploadfree" class="dropzone" action="test2.php" method="post" style="width:400px;" >
              <div class="dropzone-previews"></div> <!-- this is were the previews should be shown. -->

              <!-- Now setup your input fields -->
              <input type="text" name="free" />
              <button type="submit">Submit data and files!</button>
            </form>

    <!-- if I write the second form normally, it work fine, but by onclick event to add form, it cannot upload. 
<form id="uploadfree" class="dropzone" action="test2.php" method="post" style="width:400px;" >
              <div class="dropzone-previews"></div> <!-- this is were the previews should be shown. -->

              <!-- Now setup your input fields -->
              <input type="text" name="free" />
              <button type="submit">Submit data and files!</button>
            </form> -->

            </div>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: You need to initialize dropzone for each form you added at run time

Comment: if I write the second form normally, it work fine, but by onclick event to add form, it cannot upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your add_ptg_input() function like this. You just need to initialize dropzone on newly created form.

```
function add_ptg_input()   
{ 
    if(count<50)
    {
        var newspan = document.createElement('span');
        newspan.innerHTML = '<form id="uploadfree2" class="dropzone dz-clickable" action="test2.php" method="post" style="width:400px;" > \
        <div class="dropzone-previews"></div> \
         <input type="text" name="free" /> \
        <button type="submit">Submit data and files!</button> \
        <div class="dz-default dz-message"><span>Drop files here to upload</span></div> \
        </form> ';
        // initilize dropzone for newly added form
        $(newspan).find("form").dropzone();
        document.getElementById('add_ptg').appendChild(newspan);
        count++;
    }   
}
```

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

yes it's possible . you need listen to click event .
in click event you have to initialize the dropzone on file input.
dropzone able to multiple upload and other features .

don't initialize dropzone in page loading instead init it in click event of button that you want .

there are other ways and you can create dropzone programmatically

here is an example

```
// Dropzone class:
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", { url: "/file/post"});

or if you use jQuery, you can use the jQuery plugin Dropzone ships with:
// jQuery
$("div#myId").dropzone({ url: "/file/post" });
```

this is very simple if you want to create dropzone by click event do this :

```
// jQuery
$('your selector').click(function(event){
     $('dropzone selector').dropzone({ url: "/file/post" });
})
```

you can make a div and give it an Id and and make it hidden and initialize dropzone on it . after your dropzone created make div be visible

for example :

```
<div id="mydiv" class="hidden"> </div>
<a class="btn-dropzon-cre">create dropzone</a>
<style> .hidden{display:none;}</style>

<script>
  var dropzoneCreationFlag=false;

  $('.btn-dropzon-cre').click(function(event){

     if(!dropzoneCreationFlag)
       {
         dropzoneCreationFlag=true;
        $('#mydiv').removeClass('hidden').dropzone({ url: "/file/post" });
       }
   })
</script>
```

this will work . and you can change it in what way you want.